# FOREACH expression must not be null

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

**At declaration level i have:**

```
sqlDel text := 'DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s IS NULL';
fields text[];
field_name text;
ptable := 'myTable';
```

Somewhere behind i fill in fields so it contains 3 items - i checked it's fine. Nevertheless down below i have this for loop statement which worked fine until i added this line :

```
EXECUTE format(sqlDel, ptable, field_name);
```

**error says:**

```
ERROR: FOREACH expression must not be null
```

**Foreach loop:**

```
FOREACH field_name IN ARRAY fields
    LOOP
         EXECUTE format(sqlDel, ptable, field_name);
         raise notice 'Primary key column: %', field_name;
    END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clean - variable `fields` is null. You should to set it first.

```
fields = ARRAY['id'];
FOREACH ...
```